# How to handle old source needing floatflt.sty?

Tags: installing, texlive

I just updated to latest version of texlive (2011) for mac and suddenly I don't have the `floatflt.sty` any longer. It seems it has changed license and is no longer shipped with the distributions. (A bit of a shock considering I have been told that LaTeX is not like MS Word in that it is very backwards version compatible but I guess that discussion is for another day...)

Problem is though that I have a lot of old documents using it, so now I wonder the following:

1. What are the alternatives that I can use instead and how complicated is the conversion of my old document?
2. Given that my usage is okey okey according to this new license, how do I install it on my tex live system on my mac?

> EDIT: When I try to download the DTX and INS files from
>   http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/floatflt and run
>   tex floatflt.ins I get:
>
> ```
> $ tex floatflt.ins
> This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2011)
> (./floatflt.ins
> ! Undefined control sequence.
> l.25 \NeedsTeXFormat
>                     {LaTeX2e}[1996/12/01]
> ?
> ```

Comment: Simply use `latex floatflt.ins` instead then. INS file use `docstrip` which only uses PlainTeX. It shouldn't contain `\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}..`. But it is OK to use LaTeX instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update**: `floatflt` is now again part of TeX Live (2011) after the license issue which lead to its removal from it has been solved. An update of the existing installation will install it, e.g. try `tlmgr install floatflt` or even `tlmgr update --self --all` for a complete update.

---

LaTeX itself tends to be very well backwards compatible and most of its package (written by different people) are it as well. However, a (La)TeX *distribution* like TeX Live might decide to not include older packages any longer. You should differ between these three things.

You can still get the `floatflt` package from CTAN: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/floatflt. Just download the DTX and INS file and run `latex floatflt.ins` with both files in one folder. It will unpack the `floatflt.sty` package file. Copy this file to `$TEXMF/tex/latex/floatflt/floatflt.sty` (where `$TEXMF` is your local TEXMF structure, like `$HOME/texmf` for Linux). You might also need to update the package database (e.g. using `texhash`). You can also just place the package file in (all) your document folder(s) instead.

About the license: It can be found in the `floatflt.ins` file and states:

```
You may use the `floatflt' package freely, but at your own
risk.  The authors of floatflt.dtx and floatflt.ins (the
complete `floatflt' package distribution) can not be held
responsible for any consequence of your using any of these
files, or files created from these, including hardware,
software, and data damage.  You may not make any changes to
the files floatflt.dtx or floatflt.ins.  You are allowed to make 
changes to the `\documentclass' and/or `\usepackage' commands 
of the file `floatexm.tex'.  You may incorporate
the code from these files in other files under different
names, provided the original authors are given full credit for
their work and that you yourself take the complaints from the
user(s) of your file(s).  You may freely distribute the
files floatflt.dtx and floatflt.ins, provided that you
always distribute `floatflt.dtx' and `floatflt.ins' together
at the same time.
```

So in fact it is a free license at least for the version which is on CTAN, despite that it is listed there as "Other nonfree licenses".

---

As a replacement for in-paragraph floats you can use the [`wrapfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig) package.

Comment: Any thoughts on alternatives?

Comment: What features are you using exactly? `wrapfig` comes to mind for the in-paragraph figures.

Comment: Yea that's mostly it.

Comment: @Martin: "a (La)TeX distribution like TeX Live might decide to not include older packages any longer" sure we might, but we don't, unless the package is moved to the `obsolete` tree on CTAN (and even then, it might remain included). The problem in this case is indeed the licence: we blindly followed the indications from the catalogue which says non-free, but as you note the license seems to be free.

Comment: @mpg: Thanks. You saved me writing an email to you TeX Live people. In this case the author should have simply used the LPPL and add some additional nodes.

Comment: After some more investigation, it appears the package was removed from TL in January 2008 due to a "no commercial use" clause. In March 2008 (probably because someone contacted the author about that) the licence of the package was updated, removing this clause. For some reason, this modification went unnoticed. The package will soon be reintegrated in TL.

Comment: By the way, custom licences (and to a lesser extent, additional clauses to well-known licences) are a *nightmare* for distribution maintainers at every level (TL, Linux distros). Authors should avoid them unless they have very strong reasons.

Comment: _where_ is floatflt listed as "other nonfree licences"?  (not in the ctan catalogue, for sure.)

Comment: @mpg -- thanks for that about licences.  the problem, however, is people who don't (like the audience here) keep up with what's going on in the tex world...

Comment: @wasteofspace: It was listed so in CTAN at the time of writing. It got fixed in the meantime, as indicated by the comments.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know where you got your tl2011 from, but the current version (as available through `tlmgr` updating) *does* contain `floatflt`.

It was removed, once it was realized that its original license forbade
distribution.  Someone tracked the author down, and he said to change the
license to lppl.  So we did, and the package is back in tl, ready for tl2012.

So try:

```
tlmgr update
```

with the names of packages you need up-to-date.
(Personally I would add the flag `--all`, but that would involve an awful
lot of updating.)

Comment: When this question was posted (Aug 3rd '11) the package wasn't part of TL. The OP got his TL most likely from CTAN. Your first sentence sounds a little harsh to me.