# XeLaTeX can't find custom metafont

Tags: xetex

I just downloaded XeLaTeX from [here](http://www.texts.io/support/0001/), installed it on my Mac, and tried to use it to make a file (`haskell_101.tex` from [here](https://github.com/google/haskell-trainings/tree/master/haskell_101/slides)).

I ran `xelatex haskell_101.tex` and got the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `floatflt.sty' not found.
```

Following [these instructions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24797), I ran `tlmgr update --self --all`, got the same error. I then downloaded the `dtx` and `ins` files from `CTAN`, ran `floatflt.ins`, created the directories `texmf/tex/latex/floatflt` in `~/Library`, and then copied `floatflt.sty` there, which solved the error. (Hopefully writing all this up will help someone in the future!)

I then had to repeat those steps for `wasysym` and `fdsymbol`, at which point my `make` got part of the way through, before failing with this error:

```
kpathsea: Running mktextfm FdSymbolA-Book
/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation  for FdSymbolA-Book.
/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update ?
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input FdSymbolA-Book
This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded base=mf)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf FdSymbolA-Book
! I can't find file `FdSymbolA-Book'.
<*> ...; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input FdSymbolA-Book

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input FdSymbolA-Book

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: FdSymbolA-Book.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input FdSymbolA-Book' failed to make FdSymbolA-Book.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

! Font U/FdSymbolA/m/n/17.28=FdSymbolA-Book at 17.28pt not loadable: Metric (TF
M) file or installed font not found.
```

The folder `fdsymbol` does contain the `FdSymbolA-Book.tfm` file, in a subv-folder called `tfm`. I `mv`-d the entire contents of `fdsymbol` to `texmf/tex/latex/fdsymbol`, but still get the same error. (Is it possible it's not being found because it's in a sub-directory?)

(This amount of work exceeds my interest in reading the damn PDF, but at this point I'm in too deep to give up!)
(Also posted on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54810793/xelatex-cant-find-custom-metafont))

Comment: You have only basic TeX installed, which doesn't include all packages. You can either install the [whole thing](http://tug.org/cgi-bin/mactex-download/MacTeX.pkg) (recommended) or install the packages with `tlmgr install <packagename>`  (depending on how you installed TL you might have to `sudo tlmgr install <packagename>`).

Comment: Wow, that does the trick. Wish I'd asked earlier. Thanks very much!

Comment: also why are you using xetex if you are using 8bit tfm fonts? (it's possible but there are lots of traps for the unwary, far simpler to use 8bit fonts with 8bit pdftex and opentype unicode fonts with xetex

Comment: Fair question, the answer would be "because I have no idea what I'm doing" and because the [README](https://github.com/google/haskell-trainings/blob/master/README.md) said "The slides use LaTeX. You'll need `xelatex` installed to build them"